# Store local email id of the user in mongodb without using any input type

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I have an application where I store the details of the user in a mongoDb database named "userDetails". I am using MEAN stack to perform this function.
As the user is authenticated using his email id he used for signup, this email id can be fetched from the local users database using "<%= user.local.email %>"

```
<form id="myForm" action="#" method="post" >
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Your name:</td>
    <td><input type="text"  ng-model="user.name" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Your phone number:</td>
    <td><input type="text"  ng-model="user.phone" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Your Email Id:</td>
    <td ng-model="user.email" ><%= user.local.email %></td>
  </tr>
<input type="submit" value="Store Details" ng-click="addDetails($event)"/>
</table>
</form>
```

The name and phone number of the user are stored but the user's email id is not getting stored in the database, is there any way to do that.
this is the function I'm using to store the data in the database

```
$scope.addDetails = function(event){
    console.log($scope.user);
    event.preventDefault();
    $http.post('/userDetails', $scope.user).success(function(response){
        console.log(response);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ng-model` only works on `input` types.  Also, it sets the value from the user interaction, not from the HTML.

This is the **rare** case that [`ng-init` was designed for](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit).  `ng-init` is a special directive which allows you to evaluate an expression (such as a server side script value), and store the result in the current scope.

instead of:

```
<td ng-model="user.email" ><%= user.local.email %></td>
```

use:

```
<td ng-init="user.email = '<%= user.local.email %>'">{{user.email}}</td>
```

Please note that `ng-init` is a directive which runs at priority 450.  This means that there are some cases where `ng-init` may not evaluate until after other directives with a higher priority.  Also, `ng-init` can add unnecessary logic, so it should be used ***sparingly***.

Comment: I tried the above soluton. I'm getting the follwing error: angular.min.js:118 Error: [$parse:lexerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$parse/lexerr?p0=Unexpected%20nextharacter%20&p1=s%2032-32%20%5B%40%5D&p2=user.email%20%3D%srinidhiraichur1234%40gmail.com
I'm new to angularjs so i donno how to work this out.

Comment: Yes now it worked! And it is also storing the data in the database. Thank you so much for the help!